# base64 decode then json decode: base64.NewDecoder EOF error and json invalid character error

Tags: go, encoding, base64

I'm trying to base64 decode HTTP request, then decode it using JSON decoder.

I tried two ways to implement base64 decoder:

```
func decode(encoded []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
    decoder := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, buff)
    _, err := decoder.Read(encoded)

    return buff.Bytes(), err
}
```

This function returns an EOF error. Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/038rEXWYW6q

---

```
func decode(encoded []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    decoded := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(encoded)))
    _, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(decoded, encoded)
    return decoded, err
}
```

This works but has extra `x\00` characters so when decoding JSON we would have `invalid character '\x00' after top-level value` error.

Where is the problem with the first strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

You are creating a new buffer and assigning it to `buff`, since you have not given any source of input for it, it is empty.

```
buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
```

and `NewDecoder` is reading from empty `buff`.
Like everything in go, if you want to create a something new, you should use it's constructor which always starts with `package.Newxxx`

```
bytes.NewBuffer(src)
```

Then `decoder` is a variable which contains the actual decoded data, and it has a `reader interface`(Read method). So you can pass it to method which accepts `reader interface`, and `ioutil.ReadAll()` is one of them.

Added comments where ever necessary:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

// encoded data
var data = "eyJhY3Rpdml0aWVzIjpbXSwic3VjY2VzcyI6ZmFsc2UsImNvZGUiOjk5OTl9"

func main() {
    dec, err := decode([]byte(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(dec)) // print returned value
}

func decode(enc []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // create new buffer from enc
    // you can also use bytes.NewBuffer(enc)
    r := bytes.NewReader(enc)
    // pass it to NewDecoder so that it can read data
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, r)
    // read decoded data from dec to res
    res, err := ioutil.ReadAll(dec)
    return res, err
}
```

Infact the whole thing can be written in one line:

```
func decode(enc []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return ioutil.ReadAll(base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, bytes.NewReader(enc)))
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"activities":[],"success":false,"code":9999}
```

Comment: After down-voting, a constructive comment would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I will say it's difficult to determine from reading this post or its code comments where exactly the solution lies. I think you should make it much more explicit.

Comment: I think you should give a little description in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the line `make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(encoded)))`. The thing is, when encoding bytes, the base64 encoding uses 4 bytes for every 3 bytes of data. It then adds something called padding if your input bytes are not a strict multiple of 3 (the `=` symbols at the end of some base64 strings).

When you call `base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(encoded))`, the function under the hood performs the reverse calculation because it does not exactly know where this will end. This information will be known when the decoding actually happens.

This means that out of randomness (of your data), Go will assign a larger buffer than needed three times out of four (I am pretty sure my math is bad but you get the concept). The fix for your issue is to use the returned `n` (the first returned value) from `base64.StdEncoding.Decode(decoded, encoded)` to strip out the padding bytes.

TL;DR, your function becomes:

```golang
func decode(encoded []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    decoded := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(encoded)))
    n, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(decoded, encoded)
    return decoded[:n], err
}
```